# Contacts don't appear in contact book, but they appear in 'To' field. Why?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

When creating a new email in Microsoft Outlook 2007 all the contact's I've ever contacted appear as they should in the 'To' field when I start to type.

The problem I'm having is I need to save them to an Excel sheet but I don't want to go through each one and type them out manually so I was going to export my address book. When I looked in the contact's section there weren't any contacts there.

How do I access the contacts that are showing up in the 'To' field?

Answer (score 1):

The contacts stored in the "To" field are auto-complete entries and separate from your address book.

You can find them by pressing **Win+R**, typing the following and pressing Enter:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook
```

The entries are stored in the file with the extension `nk2`. If there is more than one file, then it will be the one that matches the name of the Outlook profile you are using.

NirSoft make [an application](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/export_nk2_autocomplete_outlook_contacts.html) that can export these entries into Outlook Contacts - although I have to admit I've never used it.